# php timezone displaying correct hours but not seconds and minutes

Tags: php

I want to display the time in different timezones, so i m using this

```
$date=new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
$date=new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')); echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

So the above code display the correct hours but it's displaying the minutes and seconds same for all the timezone.

Please help

Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the difference of time is `9 hrs 0 minutes.`

[Paris](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=195)
[Los Angels](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=137)

Answer (score 2):

Either your example is wrong or your understanding of [timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_UTC_offset) is. Seconds don't change across timezones. In some small cases minutes change by varying amounts (check the list at the bottom). In the majority of cases, it changes by hours. In all of these cases by extent, the day may change too.

```
<?php
$date=new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s P') . "\n";// -07:00
$date=new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s P') . "\n";// +02:00
$date=new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Caracas'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s P') . "\n";// -04:30
?>
```

Minutes actually change by [20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC+00:20), [24](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC+01:24), [25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9200:25), [30](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9210:30), [40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC+05:40), [44](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9200:44), [45](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC+13:45), [51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B04:51)